# TableRow get tag attribute value

Tags: android, tags, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I have 10 category, and show those in `TableLayout` and every category in a a `TableRow`.
Every category have an ID, I set every category ID in `android:tag` attribute of each `TableRow` like this:

```
<TableLayout>

  <TableRow android:id="@+id/cat1" android:tag="1" onClick="row_click">
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow android:id="@+id/cat2" android:tag="2" onClick="row_click">
    <ImageView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
  </TableRow>
  .
  .
  .

</TableLayout>
```

And when user click every row, start another activity and send category ID to it.

Now, I have 2 question:

1. Is this way I choose,corrected? (if no,please suggest a better way)
2. if yes, how to get value of `tag` attribute in `row_click` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**yes, do like this**

```
public void row_click(View v){
        System.out.println("HELO : " +v.getTag().toString());
    }
```

**Update**

NOTE : android:onClick is for API level 4 onwards, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it. So i recommended to use

```
TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tr1);

tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        row_click(v);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm targeting is >2.1